# Write java codes between Kotlin codes

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to write some java code in the kotlin file and between kotlin codes.
Is it possible?

Something like this:

```
val dayList = mutableListOf<Int>()
val monthList = mutableListOf<Int>()
int num = 45; // some code in java
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Kotlin code can only go in a kotlin (.kt) file and java can only go in a java file (.java)

You can use Kotlin methods in java code, and Java methods in Kotlin code. But you can't mix writing different languages in the same file.

Your code entirely in Kotlin would be:

```
val dayList = mutableListOf<Int>()
val monthList = mutableListOf<Int>()
val num = 45 // or val num: Int = 45
```

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot do that. You can however, use java code in kotlin (if declared in a different file) and vice versa.